# Does the "Batman Arkham Knight PS4 bundle" come with a digital or disc copy?

Tags: ps4, batman-arkham-knight

Hello im looking at ps4 bundles and i am thinking about getting the $300.00 batman arkham knight ps4 bundle but does anyone know if the game is going to be a digital or disk

Comment: These bundles seem to typically be digital, although I do not know about this specific bundle.

Answer (score 3):

The Arkham Knight PS4 bundles on every site I have seen show and list in the description a physical copy of the game. Most product descriptions are listing them as such, and most all of the promo images contain a picture of the physical box itself. From the Amazon description of the product:

> Includes: 500 GB PlayStation 4 System, 1 DualShock 4 Wireless Controller, AC Power Cable, HDMI Cable, USB 2.0 Cable, Mono Wireless Headset, and **a physical copy of Batman: Arkham Knight**

As a side note, I'm not sure where you are seeing it listed for $300, as the standard price for the bundle seems to be $399, the same as other bundles. If you are seeing it for $300, make sure it is a reputable retailer, and also ensure you are getting the bundle as specified on other sites.

**Update:** Having recieved my bundle now, I can confirm 100% it is a physical copy